# Convert duration "2d,2h,2m" to UnixTimeStamp in "date-fns"

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, date-fns

I am trying to convert this format of duration to unix time stamp eg. **( 2h, 2m, 2s)**

I could do this in moment lib with the **valueof** syntax. how to do the same in **date-fns** lib.

```
return moment(value,'M[M], d[d], h[h], m[m], s[s]').valueOf();
```

or if we can do it using plain javascript.

I have to write a custom asc/desc duration function so need to compare 2 durations using date-fns or reg javascript.

I tried the same with parse but shows Invalid date.

```
const dateString = '2h, 2m, 2s';
const date1 = parse(dateString, 'HH[HH], mm[mm], ss[ss]', new Date())
console.log(date1);
```

Comment: You should be able to do it with [`parse`](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/parse).

Comment: already tried ( updated the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few issues with your code:

1. You need single letters `h`, `m`, and `s` for the literals, not double letters.
2. Literals need to be surrounded by single quotes (`'X'`), not brackets (`[X]`).

```html
<script type="module">
// NOTE: The line below is just to make the code work here on the
// Stack Overflow site. In your own code, you can import from `date-fns`
// however you were already planning to do it.
import { parse } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/date-fns';

const dateString = '2h, 2m, 2s';
const date1 = parse(dateString, "HH'h', mm'm', ss's'", new Date())
console.log(date1);
</script>
```